# ASP.net core MVC Framework 5 Formdata not the right type when appending image

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Goal: I wish to post an image from the view to the controller using a model.

Issue: When adding the form data to the ajax method, it says,

> "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is
> not of type 'HTMLFormElement'."

What I've tried: I've done some googling and tried the HttpPostedFileWrapper as the data type in the model, and it says it doesn't exist. I also tried what the error says it should be, but that also does not exist.

I'm using Framework 5 Asp.net core MVC

Model:
[image]

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

namespace AirmotionEcommerceWebsite.Models.Admin
{
    public class AddWebProductModel
    {

        public TwebProduct product { get; set; }

        public HttpPostedFileWrapper ThumbnailImageFile { get; set; }

    }
}
```

[image]

Javascript:

```
var UploadForm = function () {

        var thumbnail = $("#Thumbnailbrowse").get(0).files;
        
        var data = new FormData(this);
        data.append("ThumbnailImageFile", thumbnail[0]);

        $.ajax({

            type: "Post",
            url: "/admin/ProductAdd",
            data: data,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {

            }
        });

    };
```

Error:
[image]

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.
    at UploadForm (ProductAdd:494)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (ProductAdd:396)
UploadForm @ ProductAdd:494
onclick @ ProductAdd:396
```

Full ProductAdd View:

```
@model AirmotionEcommerceWebsite.Models.Admin.AddWebProductModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ProductAdd";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayoutPage.cshtml";
}

<style>
    .PreviewImageThingy{
        height: 10em;
    }
</style>

<h2>Add a Product</h2>
<link href="~/css/Chosen/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/js/Chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ProductAdd", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @*@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.product.IntWebProductId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.product.BlnIsDeleted)
        @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.product.DteCreated)


        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Product Name</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.product.StrProductName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.product.StrProductName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <h5>Tags</h5>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @* Stuff here *@
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(Model => Model.product.SelectedIDArray, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.TagsList, "IntWebTagId", "StrTagName"), new { @class = "chzn-select", multiple = "multiple" })

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Thumbnail Image</h5>

            <div class="col-md-10">

                <input type="file" id="Thumbnailbrowse">
                <div id="imgPreview" class="thumbnail" style="display:none">
                    <img class="img-responsive PreviewImageThingy" id="targetImg" />
                    <div class="caption">
                        <a href="#" onclick="ClearPreview()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
                        <span id="description"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Images</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">

                <h5>Upload Images</h5>
                <input type="file" multiple id="Item-Gallary-photo-add">
                <div class="gallery"></div>


            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Is Product Active?</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.product.BlnIsActive)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.product.BlnIsActive, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Featured Item</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.product.BlnIsFeatured)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.product.BlnIsFeatured, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @{
                List<SelectListItem> dataItems = ViewBag.InventoryItemList;
            }
            <div class="form-group">
                <h5>Inventory System Item</h5>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.product.IntItemId, dataItems, "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.product.IntItemId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>MSRP</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.product.DecMsrp, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.product.DecMsrp, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Description</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.product.StrDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.product.StrDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Specs</h5>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Static Pressure in Inches w.g.</th>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.product.StrStaticPressureIn)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Air Volume (CFM)</th>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.product.StrCfm)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Noise (sones)</th>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.product.StrNoise)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Fan Watts</th>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.product.StrWatts)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Duct Diameter</th>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.product.StrDiameter)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Power Rating</th>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.product.StrPowerRating)</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="UploadForm()" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I tried this just now with no luck. When I use it how I had with the FormData(this) the product was passed, but the image was not. And now with your new way, FormData(document.forms[0]), the image is passed but not the product. I'm new to javascript, could you explain what the difference is?

Comment: Do you have an extra 'form' in Layout? Then use 'forms[1]'. I am out of ideas.

Comment: Nope, it seems to only add one or the other like the append isn't working? Thanks for all your time and help @PoulBak

Comment: I just noticed this `<input type="submit" name="Submit".....` Try changing that to: `<input type="button" name="Submit".....`. Your form is posted twice when you have type="submit" AND call ajax!

Comment: Great catch, but that didn't fix it unfortunately. Its still either the img or the products. Maybe I'm using append incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

you can replace (HttpPostedFileWrapper) with (IFormFile) i thing this will work !

Comment: This was very helpful, don't listen to the bot. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You are using:

```
var data = new FormData(this);
```

Here `this` should be a form element.

Try this instead:

```
var data = new FormData(document.forms[0]);
```

Now `data` will contain the FormData of the first form in document.

Comment: Well, this works! But it creates another problem.. So now the "product" object is null in the model but the image comes through.. any thoughts?

Comment: I see no 'product' data in your FormData. Where should 'product' come from?

Comment: It's in the model of the view. This is at the top of the page @model AirmotionEcommerceWebsite.Models.Admin.AddWebProductModel

Comment: Yes, but where should it get its value from? (default is `null`). You should probably add the vale to the FormData or other way.

Comment: It's off the screen. its a normal form that has a bunch of entries. I'll update the question with the code.